# firebug: how to break on any javascript activity?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

I really neeed to discover what is going on with a page with a very complex javascript code. Is there any way to just break, with firebug, on any javascript code that is launched?

thanks.

Comment: There're some options: Break on error, break on DOM node change, but I'm afraid, there's no such thing. Also you may use profiling to know *post factum* what happened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telling Firebug to Break as Soon as any Javascript is Executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938397/telling-firebug-to-break-as-soon-as-any-javascript-is-executed)

Answer (score 3):

Try keyword `debugger;` This will stop javascript and run debugger.
[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)